# BeautifulSoup4 Returning Empty List when Attempting to Scrape a Table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull the data from this url: https://www.winstonslab.com/players/player.php?id=98 and I keep getting the same error when I try to access the tables.

My scraping code is below. I run this, then `hp = HTMLTableParser()` and `table = hp.parse_url('https://www.winstonslab.com/players/player.php?id=98')[0][1]` returns the error 'index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0'

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class HTMLTableParser:

    def parse_url(self, url):
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        return [(table['id'],self.parse_html_table(table))\
                for table in soup.find_all('table')]  

    def parse_html_table(self, table):
        n_columns = 0
        n_rows=0
        column_names = []

        # Find number of rows and columns
        # we also find the column titles if we can
        for row in table.find_all('tr'):

            # Determine the number of rows in the table
            td_tags = row.find_all('td')
            if len(td_tags) > 0:
                n_rows+=1
                if n_columns == 0:
                    # Set the number of columns for our table
                    n_columns = len(td_tags)

                # Handle column names if we find them
                th_tags = row.find_all('th') 
                if len(th_tags) > 0 and len(column_names) == 0:
                    for th in th_tags:
                        column_names.append(th.get_text())

            # Safeguard on Column Titles
            if len(column_names) > 0 and len(column_names) != n_columns:
                raise Exception("Column titles do not match the number of columns")

            columns = column_names if len(column_names) > 0 else range(0,n_columns)
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns,
                          index= range(0,n_rows))
            row_marker = 0
            for row in table.find_all('tr'):
                column_marker = 0
                columns = row.find_all('td')
                for column in columns:
                    df.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = column.get_text()
                    column_marker += 1
                if len(columns) > 0:
                    row_marker += 1

            # Convert to float if possible
            for col in df:
                try:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
                except ValueError:
                    pass

            return df
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data that you need is just the table, you can accomplish that with `pandas.read_html()` function.

[image]

Comment: You need to see what parameters are available in the function and the HTML structure. Play around with that and see if you can read the missing data.